# tar and uuencode my folder into txt files

Tags: debian, tar

I'm trying to  full backup my project and store it into txt file.
To achive that, I used following commd
tar:Create tar.bz2 Archive File
pipeline
uuencode: create an ASCII version
my code in backup.sh:

> `tar -cjvf ImageMonitor.tar.bz2 /home/git/ImageMonitor/ | uuencode > /tmp/updateuucode.txt`

Following error happend:
tar: Removing leading `/' from member names

Answer (score 2):

That is not an error, but a notice.

Inside the tar, the path will be saved as `home/git/ImageMonitor/`.

Otherwise, if you extracted the `tar`, it will also extract to the absolute path, which is pretty unsafe and most often not what you want.

You can force `tar` to keep the `/` if you know what you're doing:

> ```
> -P, --absolute-names
>      don't strip leading '/'s from file names
> ```

[See also](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/59243/tar-removing-leading-from-member-names)

---

However, you probably don't want that path at all.
You should run

```bsh
cd /home/git
tar -cjvf ImageMonitor.tar.bz2 ImageMonitor/ | uuencode > /tmp/updateuucode.txt
```